# Rewriting URLs from https:// to http:// in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, https, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to rewrite urls from the form:

```
https://example.com/about
```

to the form

```
http://example.com/about
```

using [IIS7 URL rewriting](http://www.iis.net/extensions/URLRewrite):

```xml
<!-- http:// to https:// rule -->
<rule name="ForceHttpsBilling" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)billing/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="false" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
</rule>

<!-- https:// to http:// rule -->    
<rule name="ForceNonHttps" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)billing/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
  <conditions>
      <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^443$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
</rule>
```

<s>I'm at a loss; I've been browsing the web for examples and trying every syntax I can think of. The rewrite rules I specify simply don't appear to work *at all* for any https requests, as if all the `https://` requests are flat out invisible to the rewrite engine.</s>

rules work fine; see answer below.

Comment: Smells like a rudimentary security 'feature' to me

Comment: This smells like a Server Fault question to me...

Comment: @Charlie, no.  This is one of those questions that's both coding and admin, so leave it on the site it started on (like a lot of scripting questions)

Comment: It was really a good sample for configuration of http to https and vice-versa. I was looking for something like this only. Had tried few others but they were having one or other problem.

Comment: spin on this question- it can't be done without a valid certificate, correct? ie, I can't force https requests to go to http for the reason that I don't have a cert installed...

Comment: Can we use `action type="Rewrite"` instead of `Redirect`, so the browser would show the HTTPS shield?

Comment: @AlexKlaus did you find anything on this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Turns out that **I had port :443 bound to a different website!**

The above rewrite rules work fine for http:// to https:// rewriting and vice-versa -- though there might be more optimal or simple ways to do it.

Leaving this question here for future voyagers to find, as I didn't see many good examples of the https:// to http:// rewriting scenario on the web.

Comment: I found that with the above https to http rule resulted in all of my css, javascript, and image resources on my https pages were being fetched as http. I dropped this rule and added an outbound rule to rewrite the a href tags on my secure pages to be http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0} to force the switch from https to http.  Doesn't catch inadvertent manual navigation to non-secure pages using https but that's OK for me

Comment: Pat James, I've having this issue too. Would you mind sharing your outbound rule?

Comment: Thanks you're a life saver. :))

Answer (score 8):

This post is a little old, but I wanted to answer.  I am using ASP.Net MVC3, and Fabio's answer above didn't work for me.  The easiest solution I came up with to handle the https redirect to http, while still allowing valid https pages to request secure content was just to add Whitelist rules above my https/http redirects:

```
    <rule name="WhiteList - content folder" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^content/"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false"/>
      <action type="None"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)billing/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/billing/" redirectType="SeeOther" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="ForceNonHttps" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)billing/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^443$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 7):

please first consider **binding** https to your website for making below redirect module to work is essential (so bind your web app with a **self-signed** or **valid** certificate)

final part in web.config to redirect **https** to **http**:

```
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Force NonHTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
               <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{REQUEST_URI}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

if you need the equivalent IIS GUI in rewrite module see below image

[image]

source: look [tech-net](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dawiese/2016/06/07/redirect-from-http-to-https-using-the-iis-url-rewrite-module/) for more detail and step by step guide.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution work, but the problem is: your second instruction kill first instruction for any links is not (.*)billing/(.*), including your css, js, and images.

You can use this https to http rule:

```
<rule name="HTTPS to HTTP redirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{RequiresSSL:{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" negate="true" />
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(.+)\.(?!aspx)" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```