# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP IIS 10

Tags: iis, iis-10

I have IIS 10 running locally in my development environment. I am trying to test an SSO solution with a test ADFS instance. However, ADFS only allows for a secured endpoint to redirect to. I need to setup my local environment to change any requests that come in as https to http. Here is the configuration I have tried:

```
            <rule name="Force Http" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{REQUEST_URI}" />
            </rule>
```

The user is not being redirected and I am just getting a 404. I have tried with and without an https binding on the default website that I have the site sitting under.

Comment: HTTPS and HTTP are different connections, so you cannot rewrite but redirect.

Comment: Yes, sorry that was one iteration of me trying different things. I originally had it as a redirect.

Comment: The second mistake is that nobody would decode "{HTTP_HOST}" nor "{REQUEST_URI}" for you. Use Google to carefully learn the examples of URL rewriting rules, and see how to do that correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536120/rewriting-urls-from-https-to-http-in-iis7 and https://forums.iis.net/t/1235598.aspx?URL+Rewrite+HTTPS+to+HTTP are some of the examples I was using

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that finally worked for me:

```
<rule name="No-https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" negate="false" />
 <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
 <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
  <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^1$" />
 </conditions>
</rule>
```